# Is there a node.js extension like GWT to hide client/server communication in GUIs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, client-server

One great benefit of the Google Widget Toolkit (GWT) in Java is that is completely hides client/server communication.

When I write a user interface with GWT, I can instantiate controls and later read their content as if they were just server-side objects. No need to manually parse POST requests, particularly to map HTML  names to their corresponding HTML  IDs.

I like this concept, as it removes potential error sources and seems to speed up coding a lot.

I am about to switch to node.js and was wondering if there is anything like GWT available for user interface development in node.js / Javascript? E.g. an extension that allows me to create widgets just once, locally on the server side and then to parse read out their content after the user has submitted the form?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Take a look at https://www.meteor.com/  Watch the main video on the site.

MeteorJS has "lag compensation" which means that changes appear instantly in the browser, but are also sent to the server as fast as possible.  If the server rejects or modifies changes to the database, then the browser will update to reflect the final value accepted.  The video explains this concept very well.